# Flutter app breaks when trying to push data to firebase

Tags: exception, dart, flutter

So I am using the firebase plugin and did everything what google said to connect it to firebase, but if I try to add (create) something, it breaks the app.

This is my firebase setup:

I've downloadaded the google-services.json from firebase
added to application/build.grandle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

my grundle file to the application/app/build.grundle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.comp.appname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is the build with the error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/        ( 7903): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe4dd3840, tid 7928
D/EGL_emulation( 7903): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe4dc10c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe53dc010)
D/skia    ( 7903): Program linking failed.
I/chatty  ( 7903): uid=10087(com.comp.appname) 1.gpu identical 9 lines
D/skia    ( 7903): Program linking failed.
D/skia    ( 7903): Program linking failed.
D/skia    ( 7903): Program linking failed.
I/chatty  ( 7903): uid=10087(com.comp.appname) 1.gpu identical 2 lines
D/skia    ( 7903): Program linking failed.
W/DynamiteModule( 7903): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 7903): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 7903): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/presentationap( 7903): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/chatty  ( 7903): uid=10087(com.comp.appname) FirestoreWorker identical 2 lines
I/presentationap( 7903): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/presentationap( 7903): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader;->pathList:Ldalvik/system/DexPathList; (light greylist, reflection)
W/presentationap( 7903): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (light greylist, reflection)
W/presentationap( 7903): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->systemNativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (light greylist, reflection)
W/presentationap( 7903): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryPathElements:[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (light greylist, reflection)
W/presentationap( 7903): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->makePathElements(Ljava/util/List;)[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (light greylist, reflection)
V/NativeCrypto( 7903): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 284 native methods...
W/presentationap( 7903): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (light greylist, reflection)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 7903): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/presentationap( 7903): Accessing hidden field Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory;->defaultSocketFactory:Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory; (light greylist, reflection)
W/presentationap( 7903): Accessing hidden field Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocketFactory;->defaultServerSocketFactory:Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocketFactory; (light greylist, reflection)
I/ProviderInstaller( 7903): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903): Process: com.comp.appname, PID: 7903
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method set(Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference;Ljava/util/Map;)Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/Transaction; in class Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/Transaction; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction' appears in /data/app/com.comp.appname-GbnYcinQxOfE2R1J20iZcg==/base.apk!classes9.dex)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$6.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$6.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:374)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7903):    ... 4 more
I/Process ( 7903): Sending signal. PID: 7903 SIG: 9
Application finished.
```

It's probably worth mentioning that I use a proxy but it's configured right, and works with another app

Comment: I also tried with targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: Have you changed security rules of DB as Public?

Comment: @TirthPatel how can I check that?

Comment: Go to Firebase Console > Database > Rules

Comment: @TirthPatel Yes I it's public as I said I am able to push data with another app. 
--Your security rules are defined as public, so anyone can steal, modify, or delete data in your database

Comment: @key, can you show us the code where you make the firebase call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it,

I had to downgrade build gradle like so:
at myapp/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

and removed everything unnecessary from myapp/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I also removed all unused dependencies like image_picker and firebase_ml_vision

Comment: You cannot remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` or else firebase will not be able to find your database using your `google-services.json` file